# Flutter get device uptime

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm building a flutter application, which needs some sort of session expiry system which will log out the user from the account. Problem is, I need it to be offline compatible. One of the solutions I've found is using device's uptime, basically I want to store when was the last time user connected to the internet, save the timestamp. And when the user opens the app while offline, calculate the difference between current timestamp, and the stored timestamp. If it has exceeded the given limit, the user will be logged out. I tried using DateTime.now() for this, however, it seems like DateTime.now() is affected by the user's device time, meaning that the user can possibly exploit the system by changing his device's date and time. Which is why I came to device's uptime, however I haven't found any methods/ways/packages to get the device's uptime (which won't be affected by changes in device's date and time). Are there any ways I could do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How would uptime help you?  If the device is restarted then uptime will reset and the user would be logged out, possibly prematurely.

Comment: If the server does not return a timestamp, you can add a timestamp to the data model yourself

Comment: @bakboem I can't communicate with the server when offline that's why I couldn't get the server's timestamp

Comment: @Paulw11 I guess you're right, I didn't think of it. Thanks for mentioning that!

Comment: @treble18     isOnline? getServerTimeAndUpdateLastFetchTime() : getLastFetchTime()??DateTime.now()

Comment: @bakboem I'm trying to avoid using DateTime.now() since the user can just change the device's date and time and it would affect DateTime.now(), meaning that they can trick the system into thinking that not much time has passed, thus no need to log them out

Comment: Probably the best strategy is to record the time when they use the app. You can either store it every second or when the app is about to be suspended or whatever. Then you can check for the current time being earlier than the stored time. If it is, invalidate the login immediately. In theory they can set their device time to prolong their login but not indefinitely.

Comment: @treble18 I think the timestamp is just an auxiliary verification method, and more verification logic should be processed immediately when no network connection is found